# R - trying to make a heatmap from a matrix (all the values in the matrix are the same) using heatmap.2

Tags: r

I trying to use heatmap.2 to make a heatmap from matrix. My problem is that I am using it inside a loop and once in a while all of the values in the matrix are the same (e.g. all of the values are zeros) and I get the error message: "Error in axis(1, at = xv, labels = lv) : no locations are finite"

Is there anyway to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

you could check if all values are identical and skip the heatmap plot if this is the case.

```
m <- matrix(...)
if(!all(m[1,1] == m){
  plot...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your own breaks for the histogram.

```
x <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)   
datarange <- range(c(x)) + c(-0.1, 0.1)
mybreaks <- seq(datarange[1], datarange[2], length = 10)   
heatmap.2(x, breaks = mybreaks, 
          key.xtickfun=function() {
                    breaks <- parent.frame()$breaks
                    return(list(
                                at=parent.frame()$scale01(c(breaks[1],
                                  breaks[length(breaks)])),
                                labels=c(as.character(breaks[1]),
                                  as.character(breaks[length(breaks)]))
                                ))
                  })
```

Or, remove the color key:

```
heatmap.2(x, key = FALSE)
```